# ASP.NET Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'search'. after copying files from another project

Tags: asp.net

I have a working website website project in visual studio.
I can view all pages without a problem.

Now I copied 2 files from another Web Application Project I have:
search.aspx
search.aspx.vb

**search.aspx source snippet**

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="true" EnableEventValidation="false" MetaDescription="<%$Resources:metadescription%>" Title="<%$Resources:pagetitle %>" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/main.master" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="search" Codebehind="search.aspx.vb" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/main.master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

**search.aspx.vb source snippet**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports GlobalFunctions
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Resources
Imports generalMethods
Imports System.Globalization

Partial Class search
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

But when I try to request the page: www.test.com/search.aspx I get this error:
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'search'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page EnableViewState="true" EnableEventValidation="false" MetaDescription="<%$Resources:metadescription%>" Title="<%$Resources:pagetitle %>" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/main.master" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="search" Codebehind="search.aspx.vb" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/main.master" %>

Source File: /search.aspx    Line: 1
```

When I tried building the project, I already see the error: Could not load type 'search'.
I have no idea anymore where to look for this.

Comment: the error occured due to the change in namespaces. Make sure your namespace in the web site will not change after copying the site to a new project

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. I copied the search.aspx and search.aspx.vb and in there are no references to namespaces from my other project. Basically they look just the same as if I would normally add a new page to my current website project. So what can I do?

Comment: you have copy the page or Add existing Item to your project ?

Comment: well I suggest you to add a new page to your project and copy the whole content from the search page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I had to change "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile" in search.aspx...now it all works again.

Comment: Wow this is strange. I had a freshly generated aspx file with CodeBehind in it. Why, if it's not what has to be there?

Answer (score 2):

This can also occur if the WAP's DLL in the bin directory on the webserver is outdated and therefore does not contain a precompiled code behind for the requested page.